# Oracle SQL Developer IO error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection - Windows 10 Pro

Tags: oracle, tnsnames, oracleclient, tnsping

I am unable to connect to anything. Posting this as a beginner in Oracle SQL Developer and getting this error:

[image]

I can't find the Oracle service under Services:

[image]

The listener is also not being recognised as an identified command, similarly for SQL*Plus. Because of this shortcomings I am unable to connect to the default DB and start.

Please guide me step by step for this. The online guides have been no use to me so far.

Comment: Shortly; 1.install client such as `instantclient`, 2.add `TNS_ADMIN` parameter to the Environment variables, 3. check `tnsping <dbalias>` from command prompt. You might also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tns_admin+windows) out.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thank you for the quick response. The instantclient did help, now for the TNS_ADMIN I did add the environment variable only to find out my system doesn't have a tnsnames.ora file at all. any help ? I tries creating one but unable to save it as a .ora file

Comment: Did you install Oracle on the PC yourself? There can be different ways to set it up and not all use a tnsnames.ora if the database is installed locally. Or, if the database is installed somewhere else you will need to find out where it is (host, port, service name).

Comment: The lack of Oracle services suggests that Oracle Database is not installed at all on your PC. SQL Developer and InstantClient are only database clients; they need a server to connect to, such as Oracle Express Edition (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/express-edition-downloads.html)

Comment: SQL Developer does not come with a default database, it is just a client program for connecting to a database. If you want to host a database locally, have a look at Oracle XE, or perhaps there’s already a database on your network you should be connecting to?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Installing the oracle XE helped me to figure the issue out